# Measure of the union of sets with measure 0

Tags: measure-theory

Let's have sets that have measure 0. These sets do not have to be disjoint. Does the measure of their union equals 0? If it does, how to prove it?
I know that if the sets are disjoint, the measure of their union is equal to the sum of the measure of the given sets, whish is 0. What about the case if they are not disjoint?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: $\displaystyle\Bbb R=\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb R}\{x\}$

Comment: By "sets" do you mean two sets?

Comment: I mean countable amount of sets,  not uncountable. Let's say two or more.

Comment: If you mean "countable" then put "countable" in your question, not in a comment. Click on the "edit" button just below your question and edit your question.

Comment: By "measure" do you mean Lebesgue measure? on $\mathbb R$? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

A countable union of null sets is itself null:
$$
0 \leq \mu(\bigcup_k A_k) \leq \sum_k \mu(A_k) = \sum_k 0 = 0.
$$